# laptop keyboard does not work ubuntu 13.10

Tags: keyboard, laptop

LG T1 Laptop with Ubuntu 13.10.

I installed Ubuntu on a very old laptop (that used to work with Windows XP) with a new hard drive. However, now the keyboard doesn't work.

The internal laptop keyboard works in BIOS, so I know it is functional, but it doesn't work at all in the operating system.

An external USB keyboard works fine.

I'm a first timer in Linux, can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Could you run `lshw`, `dmesg` & `lsmod`? It sounds like the drivers are not loading

Note: This should be a comment but I have no kudos so update your original post with the outputs

Comment: Hi, thanks. I don't know what dose  "run lshw, dmesg & lsmod" mean.